How to find all occurrences of a substring in a string while ignoring some characters in Python?
I'd like to find all occurrences of a substring while ignoring some characters. How can I do it in Python?
Example:
long_string = 'this is a t`es"t. Does the test work?'
small_string = "test"
chars_to_ignore = ['"', '`']
print(find_occurrences(long_string, small_string))

should return [(10, 16), (27, 31)] because we want to ignore the presence of chars ` and ".

(10, 16) is the start and end index of t`es"t in long_string,
(27, 31) is the start and end index of test in long_string.


Using re.finditer won't work as it does not ignore the presence of chars ` and ":
import re
long_string = 'this is a t`es"t. Does the test work?'
small_string = "test"
matches = []
[matches.append((m.start(), m.end())) for m in re.finditer(small_string, long_string)]
print(matches)

outputs [(27, 31)], which missed (10, 16).

Try:
import re

long_string = 'this is a t`es"t. Does the test work?'
small_string = "test"
chars_to_ignore = ['"', "`"]

tmp = "(?:" + "|".join(re.escape(c) for c in chars_to_ignore) + ")*"
for m in re.finditer(tmp.join(re.escape(c) for c in small_string), long_string):
    print(m)

Prints:
<re.Match object; span=(10, 16), match='t`es"t'>
<re.Match object; span=(27, 31), match='test'>


One solution:
import re

def substring_search(text, value, chars_to_ignore=None):
    if not text or not value:
        return ""

    # No ignored chars
    if not chars_to_ignore:
        if value not in text:
            return ""
        substring_index = text.index(value)
        return text[substring_index:substring_index + len(value)]
    else:
        # Use regex when there are ignored chars
        regex_for_small_string = build_substring_search_regex(value, chars_to_ignore)
        matches = []
        [matches.append((m.start(), m.end(), text[m.start():m.end()])) for m in re.finditer(regex_for_small_string, text)]
        return matches

def build_substring_search_regex(value, chars_to_ignore):
    ignore_pattern = "[{0}]*?"
    ignore_string = ignore_pattern.format("".join(map(sanitize_char_for_regex, chars_to_ignore)))

    regex_string = []
    for character in value:
        regex_string.append(sanitize_char_for_regex(character) + ignore_string)
    print(f'regex_string: {regex_string}')

    return re.compile("".join(regex_string), re.IGNORECASE)

def sanitize_char_for_regex(character):
    # Escape the dash
    if character == '-':
        return r"\-"
    return re.escape(character)

long_string = 'this is a t`es"t. Does the test work?'
small_string = "test"
chars_to_ignore = ['"', '`']

print(substring_search(long_string, small_string, chars_to_ignore=chars_to_ignore))

Outputs:
[(10, 16, 't`es"t'), (27, 31, 'test')]

How it works:

Build a regex based on the substring (I took Fredy Treboux's code and converted it from C# to Python).
Use re.finditer on that regex.

Tested with Python 3.11 on Windows 10.

Looks like a simple oversight, but the No ignored chars case just returns the string, not the matches, which seems inconsistent.

@Mark thanks good point, I'll leave it for future as I don't need it now.
